# Replace a list of strings based on values in another list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of the same strings and I want to replace some substrings based on other lists.

```
my_lst = ['My name is Jack', 'My name is Jack', 'My name is Jack']

update_1 = ['My','Your','His']
update_2 = ['A','B','C']

my_lst_f = [r.replace("My", i) for r in my_lst for i in update_1][:3]
my_lst_ff = [p.replace("Jack", q) for p in my_lst_f for q in update_2][:3]
print(my_lst_ff)

--------
['My name is A', 'My name is B', 'My name is C']
```

My expected output is

```
['My name is A', 'Your name is B', 'His name is C']
```

How could I accomplish that in Python? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_lst_ff = [value.replace("My", update_1[idx]).replace("Jack", update_2[idx]) for idx, value in enumerate(my_lst)]`

Comment: If every list has a same length, it would be better to apply the method proposed by @Daniel Konstantinov.

Comment: Glad to know that! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
my_lst = ['My name is Jack', 'My name is Jack', 'My name is Jack']

update_1 = ['My','Your','His']
update_2 = ['A','B','C']

my_lst_upd = [s.replace('My', s1).replace('Jack', s2) 
    for s, s1, s2 in zip(my_lst, update_1, update_2)]

print(my_lst_upd)
# >>> ['My name is A', 'Your name is B', 'His name is C']
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
my_lst_f = [r.replace("My", update_1[i]) for i,r in enumerate(my_lst)]
my_lst_ff = [p.replace("Jack", update_2[i]) for i,p in enumerate(my_lst_f)]
print(my_lst_ff)
```

This assumes that the update_1, update_2 and my_lst lists have the same length.